# Application using vaadin4spring not starting due to not having a registered "ui" scope

Tags: java, user-interface, scope, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I'm trying to integrate the vaadin4spring library into an application (0.0.3-SNAPSHOT) and following the instructions on the readme.md file of the project I end up with an exception that states:

```
HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStageException: No Scope registered for scope 'ui'
```

I'm annotating the UI with @VaadinUI and the views with @UIScope and @VaadinView coming from the library packages.

I tried also with having the SpringVaadinServlet initialized on my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JbStatus</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.vaadin.spring.servlet.SpringAwareVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>beanName</param-name>
        <param-value>jbStatusUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JbStatus</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JbStatus</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As I still want to be able to serve REST endpoints.

I also tried having nothing in the web.xml (except from the welcome-file list) and having this mappings specified in the application.properties under /src/main/resources as:

```
vaadin.servlet.urlMapping=/ui/*
vaadin.servlet.params.productionMode=${productionMode}
vaadin.static.servlet.urlMapping=/VAADIN/*

server.sessionTimeout=400
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any ideas/suggestions

Comment: from your writing it sounds like urlmapping is responsible?  does it work without problems, if you are not fiddling with it? The error indicates more something along the lines, that spring can not pick up @Scope('ui').

Comment: Thanks @cfrick, seems to be related to a existing bug reported in Github as an issue when trying to use vaadin4spring in a "normal" webapplication project, without the use of Spring boot. I could add "@EnableVaadin" annotation in a new configuration class and this error went away, but still getting now nullpointers on static methods like UI.getCurrent() or UI.getSession()

Answer (score 0):

As per now, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/issues/76) with vaadin4spring, when used outside of spring-boot (and with XML based config).

As stated in the comments of the question, mixing with code annotated config gives a little remedy (adding `@EnableVaadin` to a config class).

The author states in the ticket, that he did not test yet outside of spring-boot

> I have not used this add-on without Spring Boot myself, so I'm pretty sure there are some problems there.

Comment: I tried already to use "@EnableVaadin" annotation but I get NPE once started everytime I try to use UI.getCurrent()